# Spark could not bind on port 7077 with public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I have installed spark on AWS.
When I try to execute on AWS it works, but spark doesn't work, when I check the sparkMaster log I see the next:

```
Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -cp /home/ubuntu/spark/conf/:/home/ubuntu/spark/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark$
========================================
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/09/12 09:40:18 INFO Master: Started daemon with process name: 5451@server1
16/09/12 09:40:18 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/09/12 09:40:18 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/09/12 09:40:18 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
16/09/12 09:40:18 WARN MasterArguments: SPARK_MASTER_IP is deprecated, please use SPARK_MASTER_HOST
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where a$
16/09/12 09:40:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ubuntu
16/09/12 09:40:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ubuntu
16/09/12 09:40:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
16/09/12 09:40:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
16/09/12 09:40:19 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set$
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7077. Attempting port 7078.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7078. Attempting port 7079.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7079. Attempting port 7080.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7080. Attempting port 7081.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7081. Attempting port 7082.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7082. Attempting port 7083.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7083. Attempting port 7084.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7084. Attempting port 7085.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7085. Attempting port 7086.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7086. Attempting port 7087.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7087. Attempting port 7088.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7088. Attempting port 7089.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7089. Attempting port 7090.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7090. Attempting port 7091.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7091. Attempting port 7092.
16/09/12 09:40:19 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7092. Attempting port 7093.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkMaster' failed after 16 retries! Co$
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My /etc/hosts is the next:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost

    52.211.60.97    server1
    52.210.246.199  client1
    52.211.71.126   client2
    52.211.20.213   client3

    # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
    ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    fe00::0 ip6-localnet
    ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
    ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

And this is my spark-env.sh:

```
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512m
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=512m
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
export SPARK_WORKER_DIR=/home/ubuntu/spark
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=52.211.60.97
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=52.211.60.97
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=4041
```

I have try the same playbook, but using a AWS VPC with private instances and VPN and it works fine. So I think there is any problem with the public IP, maybe amazon block some ports on the public IP? or what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you paste your security group

Comment: I have permit inbound and outbound all traffic, anywhere and all ports. @error2007s

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing similar issues.
This is caused as the spark master is not able to open port on specified on SPARK_MASTER_IP.
first, find your hostname by `hostname` command.
After that, make sure your machine ip address in `/etc/hosts` is mapped to given hostname.
After that, use that hostname for SPARK_MASTER_IP.
For this issue, in cluster mode, you can also mention `export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1`.

PS :- I know its late to reply, but can help other person who comes here.

Comment: The problem is if I want to open Spark Master in the Public IP.

Comment: Actually, its not a public IP but four nodes connected on same private network. So it won't help in this situation ?

Comment: My nodes works fine in private network. The problem is openning Spark in a public IP, without using a proxy

Comment: I had similar issue and error stack after applying given changes, it worked for me. If you finding it irrelevant here, I can remove it. No worries.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little bit late to reply, but I has the same issue.

I was running 1 master and 3 slaves on aws so I had a total of 4 VMs.
In my case, I put the public ip adresses in `/etc/hosts` instead of the private key.

So the configuration that worked in the end was:

In `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts


#My public keys
172.31.**.** namenode
172.31.**.** datanode1
172.31.**.** datanode2
172.31.**.** datanode3
```

And in `spark-env.sh`

```
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=namenode
export JAVA_HOME=/home/ubuntu/spark/jdk1.8.0_221
```