# Unable to bind Spark Master to any port

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Started getting this strange error on an Ubuntu based Spark server:

```
spark.deploy.master.Master --ip 68.140.243.180 --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
========================================
16/12/07 09:12:09 INFO master.Master: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
16/12/07 09:12:09 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/12/07 09:12:09 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: boescst
16/12/07 09:12:09 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: boescst
16/12/07 09:12:09 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(boescst); users with modify permissions: Set(boescst)
16/12/07 09:12:10 WARN util.Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7077. Attempting port 7078.
16/12/07 09:12:10 WARN util.Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7078. Attempting port 7079.
16/12/07 09:12:10 WARN util.Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7079. Attempting port 7080.
 ..
16/12/07 09:12:10 WARN util.Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7091. Attempting port 7092.
16/12/07 09:12:10 WARN util.Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7092. Attempting port 7093.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkMaster' failed after 16 retries!
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Note that there is no inherent problem with binding to those ports at the O/S level. To prove same i wrote a tiny `TestBind` program:

```
object TestBind {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    import java.net._
    val ssock = new ServerSocket()
    ssock.bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostName, 7077))
    println(s"Connected to $ssock")
    while (true) {
      ssock.accept
      println("got another request")
    }
  }
}
```

Let's run it:

```
$scala TestBind
Connected to ServerSocket[addr=TCA0080ALKVTAGB/192.168.0.3,localport=7077]
```

Now test it via `telnet`:

```
$telnet $(hostname) 7077
Trying 192.168.0.3...
Connected to tca0080alkvtagb.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

On the server:

```
got another request
```

So there is nothing wrong with `bind` on the server. So what's up with Spark ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447593/spark-could-not-bind-on-port-7077-with-public-ip/64540453#64540453
similar question